# Simplify $\frac{9}{2}(1 + \sqrt 5)\sqrt{10 - 2\sqrt 5} + 9\sqrt{5 + 2\sqrt 5}$

Tags: arithmetic

Simplify $\displaystyle{\frac{9}{2}(1 + \sqrt 5)\sqrt{10 - 2\sqrt 5} + 9\sqrt{5 + 2\sqrt 5}}$.

I get this when I was doing another Q,
but I don't know how to further simplify it.
Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: What was the other Q?

Comment: the square of this is solution of a quadratic equation.

Comment: Let $x$ be your number divided by $9$.  Brun's method mentioned in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152797/finding-a-closed-expression-for-a-calculated-value#comment352213_152797 finds the relation $x^4 - 50 x^2 + 125 = 0$ numerically, which suggests $x = \sqrt{25 + 10 \sqrt{5}}$.  To actually prove this, the answer by Raymond Manzoni is more appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Let's note $o:=\frac {1+\sqrt{5}}2$, $a:=\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}$ and $b:=\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}}$

then $ab=\sqrt{30+10\sqrt{5}}=5+\sqrt{5}$

Compute $(o\cdot a+b)^2$ to conclude.